# Initializer list with struct in vs2015u3

Tags: c++11

This seems trivial but doesn't work

```
    namespace Timer {

        struct T
        {
            int milliseconds = 0;
            int cmd_id = 0;
        };

        T init(const HWND hwnd) {
            T t = { 0, 0 } ;
            return t;
        }
    }
```

caller

```
auto timer = Timer::init();
```

Errors in VS2015u3 with

```
h:\lfwin32\lfwin32.h(21): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'LFWin32::Timer::T'
  h:\lfwin32\lfwin32.h(21): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

I would have thought this was standard with C++11 onwards. Is there an option I need to set?

Comment: Isn't this only a feature since C++14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you're only missing the part that VS2015 *doesn't* support C++ standards completely!

If you look at the [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) of features, you'll see that VS2015 doesn't support "NSDMIs for aggregates", which is the feature you want.

Visual Studio 2017 should support this feature though, as they increased their C++ Standard conformance.